# How to collapse all trees in registry editor?

Tags: windows-registry

While using **regedit.exe**, sometimes, it's relevant to **collapse everything** and start from a zero.

How do you collapse everything and start over? Found some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326848/how-to-reset-the-registry-editor-view-back-to-root-using-vb-script)(s) using Visual Basic, but it's not what some might want, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way:

- Type <kbd>Home</kbd> to position to "Computer"
- Exit regedit
- Next time it will start with all branches closed.

Another way is to press down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>
to collapse the current subkey. Pressing down on the <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> key
until it starts repeating is a fast way to climb out of a very deep branch.

Answer (score 2):

For example, it might be handier to use PowerShell:

1. Close `Regedit`(regedit.exe)
2. Run `Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit" -Name "LastKey"`

Also, it's possible to edit same key using ***.reg** file and executing it with contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit]
"LastKey"=""
```

These both remove its own key which stores the last viewed location  read every time the application launches.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 5 main headings. Collapse each one and you are done. I do this every time I use Regedit.

Comment: Fair enough. This option works too when choosing "Computer"(the very first one) and restarting application. Although, this won't let it automate in an adequate way.

Comment: It only take 15 - 20 seconds to collapse all

Answer (score 0):

1. In the tree (not the location bar), select any key then press Shift+Home on the keyboard to get to “Computer” on the tree.
2. Click on the left arrows to close whatever you want.

Comment: How is this different to the previous answers ?